# How this code is failing to give me an accurate answer?

Tags: python, function, class, average, static-methods

this is my code which is working fine but it is not correct. I am unable to figure out the problem

```
class MathUtils:

    @staticmethod
    def average(a, b):
        return a + b / 2

print(MathUtils.average(2, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a tiny mistake - what your code actually does is taking b, dividing it by 2 and then add the result to a. so you get 2 + 0.5 = 2.5

you need to put parentheses around a + b:

class MathUtils:

```
@staticmethod
def average(a, b):
    return (a + b) / 2
```

print(MathUtils.average(2, 1))

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are dividing b by 2 and not a + b
you can try it like that

```
return (a + b) / 2
```

Comment: Alright. thanks a lot. You saved my time. I almost forgot about brackets